# Knockout branched model / views for project planning

Tags: knockout.js, model, nested

I'm trying to create a nested (branched) Knockout model/views for a "project planning application". The data structure should be as follows:

```
--  Project (projectid,projectname)
        |--- Subproject (subid,subname)
```

Currently, my knockout model/viewmodel looks like:

```
    //----------------------------
    // model "project"
    //----------------------------
    var project = function ( projectid,
                             projectname )
    {
        var self = this;
    
        this.projectid = ko.observable(projectid);
        this.projectname = ko.observable(projectname);
    
    }
    
    
    //------------------------------
    // model subproject
    //------------------------------
    var subproject = function (  subid,
                                 subname )
    {
        var self = this;
    
        this.subid = ko.observable(subid);
        this.subname = ko.observable(subname);
    
    }
    
    
    
    //----------------------------
    // viewmodel project
    //----------------------------
    var viewmodel_project = function () 
    {
        //--------------------------
        // projects data/view 
        //--------------------------
        this.projects = ko.observableArray([]);
        var projectnumber = 0;
    
        // Add new project (open modal) 
        this.addproject = function () 
        {
            projectnumber++;
            self.projects.push(new project(projectnumber,"New Project XY"));
        };
    
    
        //--------------------------
        // subprojects data/view 
        //--------------------------
        this.subprojects = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.selectedsubproject = ko.observable();
        var subcounter = 0;
    
        this.addsubproject = function (project) 
        {
            subcounter++;
            self.subprojects.push(new subproject( 
                                project.projectid(),
                                project.projectname() + subcounter));
        };
    
    }
```

In HTML, I want to display the nested model in a tbody table,
I mean in nested loops over "projects" and "subprojects":

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <th>Mainprojects and subprojects</th>
         <th></th>
         <th href="#" data-bind="click: addproject">Add Project</th>
      </tr>
     <tbody >
        <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: projectid"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: projectname"></td>
            <td class="add" href="#" data-bind="click: addsubproject">Add Subproject</td>
        </tr>
                <!-- ko foreach: subprojects -->
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: subid"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: subname"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->    
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All I can do is, I can add projects, I can add subprojects, but I don't get them nested or branched. I don't know how to create a model like:

```
Project ( projectid,
          projectname,
          "subprojects array" )
```

Example ( just how the data structure should look like, no coding):

Projects:

```
Project 100 (

  Project ID = 100,
  Project Name = "Project 100"

  subprojects ( [ Subproject ID   = 100.10,
                  Subproject Name = "Sub Name 10" ],
                [ Subproject ID   = 100.11,
                  Subproject Name = "Sub Name 11" ] )
          ) ,

Project 200 (

  Project ID = 200,
  Project Name = "Project 200"

  subprojects ( [ Subproject ID   = 200.10,
                  Subproject Name = "Sub Name 10" ],
                [ Subproject ID   = 200.11,
                  Subproject Name = "Sub Name 11" ] )
          )
```

Any idea how to structure the Knockout model/ viewmodel would be

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two independent lists: projects and subprojects. You have subprojects refer to the project they belong to, but the projects don't know about their subprojects.

Instead of having subprojects refer back to their parent projects, the project model should include an array of subprojects as a member. That will give you the nested structure you're trying to exploit in the nested `foreach` bindings.

```
var project = function ( projectid,
                         projectname )
{
    var self = this;

    this.projectid = ko.observable(projectid);
    this.projectname = ko.observable(projectname);
    this.subprojects = ko.observableArray();
}

this.addsubproject = function (project) 
 {
     subcounter++;
     project.subprojects.push(new subproject(/* subId and name? */));
 };
```